# Is it possible to select multiple poses from Pose Library and assign to animation at a given time frame through a blender script?

Tags: animation, scripting

I have recently started using Blender, and I am wondering if I can do this... I have multiple poses selected from the Pose Library. I want to assign them to a given timestamp in animation. Is there a way I can do that through Blender scripting? Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Check the code of the Pose Library add-on shipped with Blender 3.0. It should have 90% ofg what you need.